# How can change or override sorl-thumbnail cache path and add image with absolute path?

Tags: python, django, sorl-thumbnail

I have and mediaservice website and my file storage is in other folder from media folder and I want to cache thumbnails in the other folder, How can I change sorl-thumbnail cache folder and How can I give image with absolute path to make thumbnail ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at [the class responsible](https://github.com/sorl/sorl-thumbnail/blob/master/sorl/thumbnail/base.py) for naming thumbnails produced by sorl-thumbnail.

You could subclass it and use your custom class as your thumbnail backend:

```
# in your settings.py:
THUMBNAIL_BACKEND = 'path.to.MyThumbnailBackend'


#some module, in one of yours apps:
from sorl.thumbnail.base import ThumbnailBackend
from sorl.thumbnail.conf import settings
from sorl.thumbnail.helpers import tokey, serialize

class MyThumbnailBackend(ThumbnailBackend):
    def _get_thumbnail_filename(self, source, geometry_string, options):
        """
        Computes the destination filename.
        """
        key = tokey(source.key, geometry_string, serialize(options))
        # make some subdirs
        path = '%s/%s/%s' % (key[:2], key[2:4], key)
        return '%s%s.%s' % (settings.THUMBNAIL_PREFIX, path,
                            EXTENSIONS[options['format']])
```

The previous snippet was the original code of `_get_thumbnail_filename`. You can tweak this code to generate the name at your convenience.